# So how does nginx changes process title?

Tags: c, nginx

This function implements the API to change process title:

http://lxr.evanmiller.org/http/source/os/unix/ngx_setproctitle.c

```
59     for (i = 0; environ[i]; i++) {
 60         if (ngx_os_argv_last == environ[i]) {
 61 
 62             size = ngx_strlen(environ[i]) + 1;
 63             ngx_os_argv_last = environ[i] + size;
 64 
 65             ngx_cpystrn(p, (u_char *) environ[i], size);
 66             environ[i] = (char *) p;
 67             p += size;
 68         }
 69     }
 70 
 71     ngx_os_argv_last--;
 72 
 73     return NGX_OK;
 74 }
```

What I don't understand is ,after copy the environment variables to block allocated by `ngx_alloc(size, log);`,how is that block connected with `argv[]` block?

I don't see such logic there.

And there's one line I don't understand:

```
ngx_os_argv_last--;
```

What's it for, is this line that connects the allocated block with `argv[]`?

Comment: From a comment in the source you linked to: "Fortunately, Linux and Solaris store argv[] and environ[] one after another." I think this is related to your question.

Comment: @pmg,to be honest I have read the comment many times,and I know the general idea,but after reading the code,I don't see how it implements that:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment at the beginning of the module seems to explain a lot, have you read it?

http://lxr.evanmiller.org/http/source/os/unix/ngx_setproctitle.c#L14

It appears the `ngx_init_setproctitle()` function simply sets up the memory for setting the process title and does no real changes to the title.  The comment at the beginning of the module states that it needs to setup the memory for setting the process title because argv[0] may not have the space for the new title (which is what needs to be set in order to change the title).

The `ngx_os_argv_last` variable simply points to the end of the contiguous chunk for `argv[]` and `environ[]`.  It's used later in the copy process in `ngx_setproctitle()`.  The last `ngx_os_argv_last--` is probably to account for the `'\0'` at the end of the string.

The `ngx_init_setproctitle()` create the space with `ngx_alloc()` then copies `environ[]` into the new space.  The `ngx_setproctitle()` function simply copies over `ngx_os_argv[0]` with the new value `title`.

Comment: yes I've read it several times! I've no trouble understanding the general idea,but do have trouble understanding the implementation detail...

Comment: it seems your understanding is the same as mine so far ..that is,no logic that connects the new allocated block with `argv[]` ...

Comment: If I'm reading it correctly,when copying the new title,no additional space is allocated,so if the title is longer than `ngx_os_argv_last - ngx_os_argv[0]`,buffer overflow will happen.

Comment: sure, but in order to do that, the environment would have to be pretty contrived.  ie: zero environment variables and argv[] as small as possible

Comment: Given that this is now the first search hit on argv extension I'd like to clarify (albeit years later): nginx exploits a) the fact that the strings in `argv` and `environ` are stored sequentially in memory with `argv` coming first and b) the fact that all `environ` strings can be safely re-located to another place (unlike `argv`). So the `argv[0]` entry can use the entire block that stored all `argv` and `environ` strings combined since all `environ` content was copied away, `argv[0]` already points to the beginning of the block and `argv[1]` is set to `NULL` to terminate `argv`.